# How do I read the kill icons in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

The new League of Legends patch (1.42.34) added in a "Kill Stream" (as well as a lot of other neat UI cleanups. It looks very pretty now, but I digress...) in addition to the announcements of "So and so has slain such and such" etc.

There appear to be at least three separate kill icons - A blue fireball, a yellow sword, pointing downwards, and a red sword, pointed right.

What do each of these kill icons represent?

Comment: All I can tell is that Riot fails at symbols.  Nobody seems to know; not [here](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1123119), or [here](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=365898), and even the Community Rep that replies doesn't even bother to clear it up.

Comment: I had the same question playing last night.  I also saw a series of blue swords, as if it was swinging.  You can see that one [here](http://riot-web-static.s3.amazonaws.com/images/news/August_2011/2011_08_18_announcement_system/kill2.jpg).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> [W]e went with kill, streak, streak ended.
>
> —[LoL UI Designer](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1123119&page=4)

And from their published screenshots [here](http://riot-web-static.s3.amazonaws.com/images/news/August_2011/2011_08_18_announcement_system/kill1.jpg) and [here](http://riot-web-static.s3.amazonaws.com/images/news/August_2011/2011_08_18_announcement_system/kill2.jpg):

- Single Yellow Sword: Kill

   [image]
- Multiple Blue Swords: Kill Streak

   [image]
- Downward Sword: Breaking someone's kill streak

   [image]

The background is if it was a kill for your team (green) or theirs (red)

Comment: Weird. I mean, I think this is probably correct, but in the one game I've played post-patch, the downward sword showed up on the 2nd kill (after our fiddles dived the tower for firstblood) so I think it might have more to do with bounty (i.e., the kill is 300g+) than a kill streak per se. Will try to verify that.